# Is there a formula to find the MAPE for $Y_t$ if we know the MAPE for $\Delta$log($Y_t)$?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, econometrics

Is there a simple formula to find the MAPE for $Y_t$ if we know the MAPE for $\Delta$log($Y_t)$ ~ iid N($\mu$,$\sigma^2$)?

Is there an algebraic relation between the two?

What if I use RMSFE instead? Or some other measure of forecast accuracy.

Comment: If there is a formula it is certainly not simple. Furthermore MAPE is a very bad fit statistic for $\Delta\log(Y_t)$, since you should have a sizeable amount of values close to zero, which should make MAPE large. Also do you claim that MAPE is normal, or $\Delta\log(Y_t)$ is normal?

Comment: I assume $\Delta log(Y_t)$ is normal.

Comment: That's a good point mptikas, I did not think of that

Comment: Moreover, I just thought recently that it is a bit weird that I'm using MAPE if I'm interested in minimising MSE loss. But I'm not sure if that's relevant to this question. Just a thought.

Comment: Ok, suppose your data follows normal distribution. But MAPE is calculated using fit from some model and you did not tell what model is that. If you have the data and the model, then simply transform back to levels and then calculate MAPE. And yes if you minimise MSE, MAPE is probably not what you want. Although it gives some idea about the fit, it is not best statistic for forecast accuracy.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Do you think it would help to use the actual percentage change instead of the differenced logarithms?

Comment: Differenced logarithms is growth expressed in percentages. In this case mean absolute error has meaningful interpretation.